# Filling input values progmatically on Mobile Browsers

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I have to implement post code lookup on a website that I am implementing. On the Address Form, there is a field for postal code. When the user types in a post code and navigates to the next field, a REST call is made to an API to fetch the city and canton associated with that post code. I then use jQuery to fill in those values in the respective fields.

We have certain cases where a certain postal code can belong to two different cities (within the same country) and we need to handle those, which we do. The code looks as follows:

```
$.getJSON(requestUrl, function (json) {
    // Clear the list
    $(postCodeList).empty();

    if (!json) {
        return;
    }
    if (json.length > 1) {
        // Fill the list with cities
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            item.setAttribute("data-canton", json[i].canton);
            item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json[i].city));
            if (json[i].plz === parseInt(plz, 10)) {
                postCodeList.appendChild(item);
            }
        }

        // Append the list
        var wrapperDiv = $citySelector.parent();
        $(postCodeList).css("z-index", 100);
        $(wrapperDiv).append(postCodeList).focus();


        // Handle onClick on suggested city
        $("#post-code-list li").on("mousedown touchend", function (evt) {
            var suggestedCity = $(this).text();
            var suggestedCanton = this.getAttribute('data-canton');

            $cantonSelector.val(suggestedCanton).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur");
            $citySelector.val(suggestedCity).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur").focus();

            $("#post-code-list").hide();
            evt.preventDefault();
        });

    } else {
        // Don't return an array in this case
        if (json.plz === parseInt(plz, 10)) {
            $cantonSelector.val(json.canton).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur");
            $citySelector.val(json.city).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur").focus();

            $("#post-code-list").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

In case when we receive an array (`json.length > 1`), our code works exactly as expected. The relevant part is:

```
$cantonSelector.val(suggestedCanton).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur");
$citySelector.val(suggestedCity).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur").focus();
```

The chain `focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur")` is needed to trigger the validation for that is how parsley is setup.

Now, we come to the case where we receive single values `json.length <= 1`. In this case, we execute the following code:

```
$cantonSelector.val(json.canton).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur");
$citySelector.val(json.city).focus().trigger("input").trigger("blur").focus();
```

The code is exactly the same. However, in this instance, we encounter the following problems.

**Chrome**

- The canton value does not get autofilled.

**Safari**

- The values are filled out, but focus (and viewport) remains on the canton select field. And the options for the canton are still displayed.

**Firefox**

- Values are filled out, but focus (and viewport) remains on the canton select field.

The expected behaviour is that both the canton and city are filled out, the canton field is validated and the focus (and the cursor) remains on the city field. This works on desktop, but not on mobile.

Could someone please explain me as to what it is that I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks